# How can I determine which version of a pod I have in my project?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I inherited an Xcode project that uses CocoaPods. It looks like there's only one pod installed and it's checked into source control so I haven't had to install/use CocoaPods at all so far. I believe I have [an issue with an older version of CocoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1546) so I'm looking to updating the whole thing (both the workspace and the pod itself). I'd like to ID which version of the current pod I have installed so I can review the version history before updating the pod. Is this information stored somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Podfile.lock may indicate the versions installed. i.e open the file but dont edit.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't think I had a Podfile.lock file but it turns out it just wasn't in my Xcode workspace. I see it now and can see the version. Thanks!